# how to start h2o flow after reboot laptop?

Tags: h2o

I have follow the instruction to install flow 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HVx9Jqr34Q

it works perfectly. But if I restart my laptop, then i open "http://localhost:54321" it shows not connected.

Should I rerun the command "java -jar h2o.jar"? is that alway required if I want to open flow after computer reboot? is that an easy short cut to start flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to re-run `java -jar h2o.jar` after rebooting. Alternatively, you could have your OS start it, by running that command, during the boot process; the instructions for that vary by OS (and are outside the scope of StackOverflow, but are easy to google).